# Only evaluate Excel function when trigger is turned on

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom Excel function with a long run time. I would like to keep automatic formula calculations turned on in my workbook, but only evaluate this particular formula when I toggle a cell to TRUE (it would also be fine if somehow the formula could be toggled via VBA). One option I have seen suggested is to wrap the function call in an IF() statement. For example, suppose the formula is in cell `A1`, an argument to the formula is in cell A2, and the TRUE/FALSE trigger is in cell `A3`. Then the formula in `A1` would look like

`=IF(A3, MYFUNC(A2), A1)`

This will evaluate `MYFUNC(A2)` if `A3==TRUE`, otherwise it will return the existing value of the cell. However, the problem I find with this is that if I toggle `A3` from TRUE to FALSE and then back to TRUE then `MYFUNC()` will always re-evaluate, even if its input `A2` has not changed. I have multiple calls to `MYFUNC()` in different parts of the workbook, and because the function is time consuming to execute I only want it to execute if one of its inputs have changed. Note that while here `MYFUNC()` takes a single scalar input in reality it could become more complex and take multiple ranges as inputs.

Comment: is it sufficient to toggle _all_ formula evaluation?

Comment: Are you thinking of turning off automatic formula evaluation, and instead having the user press Calculate Now on the ribbon each time they want to re-evaluate the whole workbook? I would prefer not to go this route, since I want to keep automatic evaluation on for everything except MYFUNC.

Comment: What about `Worksheet_Change` event, with testing Target for the input range of your formula?

Comment: If you put this `=IF(A3, MYFUNC(A2), A1)` in A1 this won't work because A1 is referencing to itself in a circle. I think there is only 2 solutions to the issue but they are not exactly what you like: 1. Turn calculation to Manual (trigger off) and Automatic (trigger on) but this means when it is on manual other formulas will not calculate neither. Or 2. Write a VBA code that does the calculation on a button click instead of a user defined formula. So it only re-calculates when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, I think this is unexpected and you don't really want a custom function at all, but to

- switch your `Function` to just VBA `Public Sub MyFunc(..`
- add a button and "Assign Macro" to call your logic

This would probably behave much more the way a user expects

---

If you *must* have a `Function`, consider short-circuiting it internally by adding a dedicated check

With some default arguments to make this easier to use (I would recommend making Trigger required, but again prefer pure VBA with a Macro to trigger it)

```vb
Function MYFUNC(Target as Range, _
    Optional Trigger As Range = A2, _
    Optional UnTriggeredDefault As Variant = 0) As Variant

    ' Bonus Features
    '   logic to detect improper Trigger range
    '   logic to allow UnTriggeredDefault to be a Cell/Range
    '   make Default an Error like xlErrNA ?
    '   accept other values or detect False for Trigger.Value

    If Trigger.Value != True Then
        MYFUNC = UnTriggeredDefault
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' rest of your logic

End Function
```

An advantage to this is that you can add an additional column (or Range which is dedicated to some larger or smaller Range?) to trigger individual calculations on, while also preventing recalculating every instance of `MYFUNC()` (undoing work which was already done if A2 is set False)

Sorry, I don't have a copy of Excel to test this with, but I'm open to improvements!

Comment: `!=` does not exist in VBA, either use `If Not Trigger.Value = True` or `<>` instead. Also this will only output a default value if the trigger is false and not the last calculated value of the function as the OP wished (which I think is not possible at all). Also `As Range = A2` won't work as you have to use constants here and cannot use variables.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you! and I'd indeed recommend using another column for tracking, either that a calculation was done (for a Macro) or to denote calculation for their Function (though it honestly seems like unexpected use and fraught with perils)